# Open modal view controller with gesture

Tags: ios, swift, transition, swipe, gesture

I have to implement a swipeable `UIView` at bottom of my `UIViewController` who have a pull up gesture like in ios 10 Apple Maps app, to open a view controller.

Anyone have an idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: can you explain more, can you post some pictures, gif or something?

Comment: Try a custom UIView, and add a UISwipeGesture on the View controller.

Comment: @ReinierMelian the animation would by like that https://github.com/52inc/Pulley ... but with implement this.